# Homestead up cannot find current available boxes and try to download a new one

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I downloaded `laravel/homestead` box and it show is available. Unfortunately, whenever I am trying fire up `homestead up`, it says cannot find the box and trying to install a new one. The reason is it is finding with v0.3 and below. How can I change it to use box version v0.4.1.  I attached the screenshot of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update your box by running

```
vagrant box update --box laravel/homestead
```

If you cannot update or still want to use your existing box, you could remove the `config.vm.box_version` from your Vagrantfile and it will not check the version of the box